# How to separate parameter from Output

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating simple project in which i want users location(latitude and longitude).I did it successfully.I did it like ;

```
self.locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = 10;

self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

...

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{



 // Add another annotation to the map.
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = newLocation.coordinate;
[self.map addAnnotation:annotation];

// Also add to our map so we can remove old values later
[self.locations addObject:annotation];

// Remove values if the array is too big
while (self.locations.count > 1)
{
    annotation = [self.locations objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.locations removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    // Also remove from the map
    [self.map removeAnnotation:annotation];
}


if (UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
    // determine the region the points span so we can update our map's zoom.
    double maxLat = -91;
    double minLat =  91;
    double maxLon = -181;
    double minLon =  181;

    for (MKPointAnnotation *annotation in self.locations)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = annotation.coordinate;

        if (coordinate.latitude > maxLat)
            maxLat = coordinate.latitude;
        if (coordinate.latitude < minLat)
            minLat = coordinate.latitude;

        if (coordinate.longitude > maxLon)
            maxLon = coordinate.longitude;
        if (coordinate.longitude < minLon)
            minLon = coordinate.longitude;
    }

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.span.latitudeDelta  = (maxLat +  90) - (minLat +  90);
    region.span.longitudeDelta = (maxLon + 180) - (minLon + 180);

    _latitude1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Latitude:%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    _longitude1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Longitude:%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];


    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.fetchtokenString1 = [NSString stringWithString:_latitude1];
    appDelegate.fetchedriveridString1 = [NSString stringWithString:_longitude1];





    NSLog(@"%@",_latitude1);
    NSLog(@"%@",_longitude1);


    // the center point is the average of the max and mins
    region.center.latitude  = minLat + region.span.latitudeDelta / 2;
    region.center.longitude = minLon + region.span.longitudeDelta / 2;

    // Set the region of the map.
    [self.map setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"App is backgrounded. New location is %@", newLocation);
}
```

I'm getting output like this `<+37.33370957,-122.06381723> +/- 5.00m (speed 34.53 mps / course 294.26) @ 5/26/16, 3:38:54 PM India Standard Time`
I want to send Latitude and longitude separately to server,
**Now my question is** how should i separate that lat-long from above output. means I want to separate `+37.33370957`this in one string and `-122.06381723`this is another string... How can i do like this??
please suggest any solution for this issue...!

Comment: For people to help you need show the code you use to produce that output, and what you have tried to obtain the lat & long as strings. Make sure you include the declarations of any variables you use in your code - what the types are will impact the solution. You can edit your question to add this information, **do not** add it in comments.

Comment: I update my question...@CRD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
NSString *rawString = @"<+37.33370957,-122.06381723> +/- 5.00m (speed 34.53 mps / course 294.26) @ 5/26/16, 3:38:54 PM India Standard Time";
NSRange range1 = [rawString rangeOfString:@"<"];
NSRange range2 = [rawString rangeOfString:@">"];
NSString *string = [rawString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(range1.location + range1.length, range2.location - range1.location - range1.length)];
NSArray *components = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *latitude = [components objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *longitude = [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

Another way:

```
NSString *rawString = @"<+37.33370957,-122.06381723> +/- 5.00m (speed 34.53 mps / course 294.26) @ 5/26/16, 3:38:54 PM India Standard Time";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\\<)(.*?)(?=\\>)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:rawString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [rawString length])];
NSArray *components = [[rawString substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:0]] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString *latitude = [components objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *longitude = [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

Probably there's even a better way with regex but sadly I'm not good at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try as
<+37.33370957,-122.06381723> +/- 5.00m (speed 34.53 mps / course 294.26) @ 5/26/16, 3:38:54 PM India Standard Time

1. put it in string variable
2. split string by ">" character and put first split string value in another string variable
3. Now split it by "," character you get to split string and then use  replace string method for "<" character
4. Now you can get it lang & lot for sending it